# Generic type in constructor parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I want to use a generic type in a constructor parameter like this:

```
public class Myclass
{
    public Myclass<T>(IEnumerable<T> ListeValeurChampPerso, string str, int a)
     {
       foreach (var vr in ListeValeurChampPerso)
       {...
       }
    }
}
```

but it generates me a lot of errors. How can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer, you can't. What you can is to have generic class: `class MyClass<T>`

Comment: but you can create static factory method with generic parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the class generic, you can't have a generic constructor because it would be meaningless because you couldn't use T outside of the constructor.

This will work fine.

```
public class Myclass<T>
{
    public Myclass(IEnumerable<T> ListeValeurChampPerso, string str, int a)
     {
       foreach (var vr in ListeValeurChampPerso)
       {...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i made the class generic but it generetes errors in this lines (when i use the parameters of the Type T):                                                              foreach (var vr in ListeValeurChampPerso)
       { vr.item = 1; ...
       }

Comment: What errors do you get on what lines of code, the code in my example compiles just fine as is.

Comment: when i put vr.param1 = 1; or somrthing like this i get the error: T does not contain a definition for param1 and i don't want to use dynamic so i have to do it like this                                          foreach (var vr in ListeValeurChampPerso){ vr.param1 = 1}

Comment: Thats because T could be anything, if you did `var obj = new MyClass<string>()` then string does not have a property `param1`. If you want to access specific members of T the you heen to constrain it to a base class or interface. e.g. `public class Myclass<T> where T : ISomeInterface` then you would be able to acces any members defined on `ISomeInterface`

Comment: Actually i have two classes which have 4 parameters in common so i make an interface which contains this 4 parameters but i get this: The interfaces can not contain fields

Comment: You need to ensure they are properties not fields, e.g. `public string MyProp {get;set;}`

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! (string MyProp {get;set;} without "public")